# Why is component function not being called when button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

Any idea why `console.log('hey');` is not logged in the browser console when I click the button?

I'm trying to show/hide the `sub-component` if `<button (click)="hey">Click me!</button>` is clicked.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public flag = false;
  public hey() {
    console.log('hey');
    this.flag = true;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="hey">Click me!</button>
<div *ngIf="flag">
  <sub-component></sub-component>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

Comment: `<button (click)="hey()">Click me!</button>` you are missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call a method.

```
<button (click)="logThis('hey')">Click me!</button>
<div *ngIf="flag">
  <sub-component></sub-component>
</div>
```

And then in your component just:

```
logThis(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

The thing is that `(click)` is the clicking event. And you have to tell him what to do when that event triggers. In this case, we are calling `logThis()`.

**Update:**

I didn't see that you actually declared a `hey()` method and that you just forgot your `()`.

I thought you were trying to pass a string directly. My bad!

Anyways, this could be useful for others! :D